# Why is EDM class a partial class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added a new ADO.Net EDM item in my Visual Studio Porject.

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Rajat.Personal.EF
{
    public partial class PracticeContext : DbContext
    {
        public PracticeContext()
            : base("name=LocalContext")
        {
            this.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
        }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.firstname)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.lastname)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.emailaddress)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .Property(e => e.password)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

}

I have 2 questions

1. Why is PracticeContext a partial class?
2. Why is Users property virtual ?

Comment: The reason behind them: (1) Partial class used to separate auto-generated code from business logic code, which then compiled as a single class. (2) Virtual `DbSet` property enables so-called lazy loading mechanism which overridable on inherited classes.

Comment: Suggest you need to brush up OO and C# basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generated as a `partial class` so that you can extend the class in a separate file and avoid losing any edits that you've made when the context is next regenerated.

It uses `virtual` on properties so that you can override them in an inherited class to provide some alternative behaviour.